# lxml findall and reverse order

Tags: python, lxml

How to print all findall elements in reverse order ?

```
labels = tree.findall(label)

for label in labels:
     print etree.tostring(label)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or maybe something like this:

```
labels = ET.findall(label)
alist =[]
for one_label in labels:
     alist.append(etree.tostring(one_label))

print sorted(alist, reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a [`reversed`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reversed) function:

`for label in reversed(labels)`